# Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer

Tags: object, initializer

When I try to compile using Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition the example below that I extracted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx, VS throws out 9 errors: 
1) 6 errors are about the 6 gets/sets "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern", and 
2) 3 errors are about the { and } after the new StudentName, i.e. A new expression requires () or [] after type.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Object initializers  were not introduced until .NET 3.0/VS 2008.  Just out curiousity, why are you using a code sample for VS 2012 in VS 2005?

Comment: I encounter similar issues when I used Reflector on some other dll so I google for help and found that example. I continue using my old VS 2005. Think it's time to upgrade to at VS 2008.

Comment: I'd suggest going all the way to VS 2012, as you'll be missing out on a lot of stuff if you only go to 2008 (like improved WCF, parallel library, a whole bunch of async stuff in 4.5, etc).

Comment: "The example below", which example below?

Comment: At first I copied the example below, but the editor complained of the format so I removed the codes but without updating the content.

Answer (score 1):

The sample there requires a newer compiler, it uses features not available with the compiler used by VS 2005. That document is part of the VS 2008 documentation, so VS 2008 or newer should be able to compile it.

Comment: When I clicked on the link it took me to the 2012 version (which is probably just about the same thing); but you're correct about not being able to do it in 2005.

Comment: @Tim The "Other versions" menu can get you to the version as it was in the 2008 documentation.